# Elastic-Search count Aggregation on the time difference between two fields

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, kibana-6

I'm trying to count aggregate the time difference (in minutes) between two date fields of the elastic search documents in an hourly based.

The documents in elastic search are like this:

```
  [
    {
      "name": "rakesh",
      "age": "26",
      "email": "rakesh@gmail.com",
      "createdDate": "1549458543000",
      "updatedDate": "1549458723000"
    },
    {
      "name": "sam",
      "age": "24",
      "email": "samjoe@elastic.com",
      "createdDate": "1549458543000",
      "updatedDate": "1549458723000"
    },
    {
      "name": "joseph",
      "age": "26",
      "email": "joseph@gmail.com",
      "createdDate": "1549458543000",
      "updatedDate": "1549458723000"
    },
    {
      "name": "genny",
      "age": "24",
      "email": "genny@hotmail.com",
      "createdDate": "1549458543000",
      "updatedDate": "1549458723000"
    }
  ]
```

Using the above documents, we need to get the difference of the updatedDate and createdDate and count of the documents which are having the same timediff which are crated in the same hour.

from the above sample data, we need to extract the output as -

```
 for hour 1549458000000 there are 4 documents which are updated within the 4 minutes 
 of time.
```

I can able to get the timediff using script field

```
  "script_fields" : {
      "timeDiff" : {
        "script" : "doc['updatedDate'].value - 
        doc['createdDate'].value"
      }
     }
```

and 
count aggregation i tried is

```
 {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
      "hour": {
        "date_histogram": {
          "field": "createdDate",
          "interval": "hour",
          "time_zone": "Asia/Calcutta",
          "min_doc_count": 1
        },
        "aggs": {
          "mail_count": {
            "value_count": {
              "field": "email"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": []
      }
    }
  }
```

With the above query i can able to get the total documents in that particular hour. 
Is there anyway to combine these two outputs into a single one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the current query you have.

Comment: @Val , Thanks for the reply .. Currently, I am currently aggregating the documents, based on the hours (date histogram aggregation) with the count of the documents in that particular hour ..i was unable to integrate the script field (ex: doc['@updatedDate'].value - doc['createdDate'].value) in that aggregation.

Comment: Please share your query as a starting point for solutions :-)

Comment: @Val. updated the queries in the question itself.. It would be helpful if you give the idea to to combine them if possible. Thanks in advance.